# Sklearn AdaBooster and Base estimators

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn, adaboost, boosting

I want to use the sklearn [AdaBoostRegressor](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.AdaBoostRegressor.html)
with different base estimators. The general [AdaBoost introduction](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/ensemble.html#adaboost) does not help too much, since they use the 
[DecisionTreeClassifier](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier.html)

Where do I find a list of all base possible base estimators?

Could I use a neural Network, too?

What qualifies the possible base estimators?

Comment: did you try passing a neural network, using that `base_estimator` parameter? what happened?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I use XGBoost to boost other models (eg. Naive Bayes, Random Forest)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58572881/can-i-use-xgboost-to-boost-other-models-eg-naive-bayes-random-forest) (the *answer*, if not the question itself).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any Regressor model which depicts the sklearn's [`RegressorMixin()`](https://scikit-learn.org/dev/modules/generated/sklearn.base.RegressorMixin.html?highlight=regressor#sklearn.base.RegressorMixin) can be fed as the base estimator.

Yes, you can use neural network or simple linear regressor as base estimators.